# Error while fetching gallery

Tags: php, sql

i have a problem with this code. The gallery function is giving me error. I am new to php so, I just found this gallery ad really want to implement it in my site.

Error from comment: `Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\trauma\gallery.php on line 5.`

This is my code:

```
   <?php
 require_once("connections/connection.php"); 
include_once('header.php');

 public function gallery()
{
$qry = $this->select("photocategories WHERE pho_published=1");
 $count = 1;
 while($arr = $this->fetch($qry))
 {
  $qry1 = $this->select("photos WHERE pht_pho_ID=$arr[pho_ID]");
  $arr1 = $this->fetch($qry1);
 ?>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <a href="photos.php?pho_ID=<?php echo $arr['pho_ID']; ?>">
     <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="uploads/photos/thumbs/<?php echo $arr1['pht_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo                           
      arr['pho_title']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="caption">
     <h1 style="line-height:10px; text-align:center;"><?php echo $arr['pho_title']; ?></h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
<?php
 if($count % 4 == 0) { echo '</div><div class="row">'; }
 $count++;
 }
}
```

Comment: That's not a function. It was supposed to be an object method. It doesn't work without the `class` around it.

Comment: Yawn. So, could you let us in on what that error says?

Comment: Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\trauma\gallery.php on line 5. This is the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `public` in-front of the function so that it looks like this:

```
function gallery() { ... }
```

The `public` keyword is only for [declaring the visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) of methods and properties.